# Problem with texture coordinates on a triangle based terrain in a-frame

Tags: 3d, aframe, texture-mapping

Ok this might be a little all over the place, since I'm pretty much a beginner when it comes to anything graphics related. Thus I probably misuse some terms here, sorry for that.

Also if the thing I try to achieve is already solved in a way easier manner I'd be grateful for information on that, but I would mainly want to understand this problem first. :)

What I tried to achieve:
I want to create a terrain for a little 3d world I want to build with for pretty much myself in my Vive.
The terrain (when working) should allow textures to be blended on them. Here I just add textures. And this is where my problem at the moment lies.

Ages ago I wrote something similar in XNA. I used rbga as color for the vertices and blended it based on the intensity of each channel. So I had up to 4 textures per vertex.
Based on this memory and a vague idea how it should work I did this in plain javascript:

```js
const heightmap2 = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [2, 0, 0],        
    [3, 0, 0],
    
    [0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1],
    [2, .5, 1],        
    [3, 0, 1],
    
    [0, 0, 2],
    [1, 0, 2],
    [2, 0, 2],        
    [3, 0, 2],
    
    [0, 0, 3],
    [1, 0, 3],
    [2, 0, 3],        
    [3, 0, 3],
    
    [0, 0, 4],
    [1, 0, 4],
    [2, 0, 4],        
    [3, 0, 4],
    
    [0, 0, 5],
    [1, 0, 5],
    [2, 0, 5],        
    [3, 0, 5],
];
let mapWidth = 3;
let mapHeight = 5;

let globaltexture = '#chesstexture'; 

// Just did this to "wait" for the dom to load.... I know not ideal, just wip
setTimeout(() => {
    const hmElem = document.getElementById('heightmap');    
    
    for(let i = 0; i < heightmap2.length; i++) {
        
        let row = Math.floor(i / (mapWidth + 1));
        let isLast = row !==  Math.floor((i + 1) / (mapWidth + 1));
        
        // We don't create a last triangle as it would return from the right side to the left side and be reversed.
        if(isLast) continue
        
        if(heightmap2[i][2] % 2 === 0) {
            hmElem.appendChild(createLowerTriangle(i))
            
            // Skip out of border vertices
            if (row === 0 || row >= mapHeight) continue
            hmElem.appendChild(createUpperTriangle(i));
        } else {
            hmElem.appendChild(createUpperTriangle(i));
            // Skip out of border vertices
            if (row === 0 || row >= mapHeight) continue
            
            // These are definately borked as in textures are tilted once any elevation is set...
            hmElem.appendChild(createLowerTriangle(i))
        }
    }
    
}, 10)

function createTriangle(a, b, c) {
    let tri = document.createElement("a-triangle");
    tri.setAttribute('src', globaltexture);
    tri.setAttribute('vertex-a', a);
    tri.setAttribute('vertex-b', b);
    tri.setAttribute('vertex-c', c);
    return tri;
}

function createUpperTriangle(pos) {
    return createTriangle(heightmap2[pos].join(' '),  heightmap2[pos+1].join(' '), heightmap2[pos - mapWidth].join(' '));
}

function createLowerTriangle(pos) {
    return createTriangle(heightmap2[pos + mapWidth + 1].join(' '),  heightmap2[pos+1].join(' '), heightmap2[pos].join(' '));
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <a-scene debug>
    <a-assets>
     <img id="chesstexture" src="/assets/textures/chess.jpg">
    </a-assets>
      <a-sky color="#cee8db"></a-sky>
      <a-entity position="0 0 -10" id="heightmap">
      </a-entity>
      <a-entity light="type: ambient; color: #BBB"></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
  </html>
```

This does not include blending based on vertex colors or anything, it is simply an array full of coords and each coordinate is an edge for a triangle.

Then all of those are iterated over and added to the dom.
The result it the correct heightmap I expected it to be. As a texture I create a "chess board" with numbers in each corner.

Like so:

1 3

7 9

My problem is that once I add elevation into my heightmap (simply a number > 0 in the Y coordinate of any line) is that it correctly positions the triangles but it also "rotates" the textures. Sadly I don't know how it aligns itself.

Technically I would later remove this "draw texture on triangle feature" anyway as I want to blend it anyway, but still this bothers me quite a bit.

I mainly want to understand how to control texture positioning here.

In case my explanation was hard to understand I'll add an image how it looks at the moment. I marked one of the "broken" triangles in blue.
[image: The blue marked one is one of the broken.]

Comment: The correct approach is not to create a separate triangle / entity for each triangle. That would be very unperformant, and doesn't work by just applying a single texture. You should be using either a vertex shader with a height map texture OR manipulating the vertices of a single geometry (`el.getObject3D('mesh').geometry.attributes.position`). Will take some reading of the three.js API and some StackOverflow questions .Your code should also be contained in components, rather than randomly in the HTML page. Can perhaps provide a full answer later.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I was pretty sure it's not a great approach, but I was missing all the search terms. I'll look into what you wrote (perhaps on the weekend though) As for the components, sure, it was just a quick poc. :) I later wanted to set up a smarter node server and probably typescript too. Just wanted to make sure it does work and I can get something to display.

Comment: Also if you height map is a grid, you could generate a height map by creating a canvas and drawing on it, where black and white and shades in between stand for different heights. If your height map is a grid, then it's easy to generate it using fillRects. If it's not a grid, then never mind.